# React pure component with hooks and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm struggling about what may be a good way to implement components in React with a good coding pattern.

Normally I know the idea of presentational and container components: the presentational only shows html and receive everything from props (data and callbacks); the container orchestrate the presentationals retrieving and mutating data and passing it to them by props.

Now I'm using redux with redux toolkit and rtk query, with hooks.

Following that approach, the container component should be the only one allowed to useSelector and useDispatch and useQuery. But I find a lot easier and cleaner allowing the presentationals to select and fetch and dispatch what they really need, instead of making a giant container component which manage all the data for its children with a huge list of state and fetch access. This is true especially for lists, where it is a lot easier and cleaner just letting each child to retrieve its own data (fetched or from state), or for deeply nested presentationals.

However I'm mixing up container components with fake presentationals which anyway retrieve something when it is easier and true presentationals maybe for general and totally reusable components. Also the components tree is very messy (like container->fake presentational->container->fake presentational->true presentational->true presentational ...).

At the end I feel like I don't have good rules and the code is messed up.

Are container and presentation components still a good coding style which follows a best practice pattern but in the world of hooks and redux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The React Container Pattern advocated by Dan Abramov has for all intents and purposes been deprecated since the introduction of React hooks in 2018.

See Dan's blog entry [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) from 2015.

His update from 2019:

> Update from 2019: I wrote this article a long time ago and my views
> have since evolved. In particular, I don’t suggest splitting your
> components like this anymore. If you find it natural in your codebase,
> this pattern can be handy. But I’ve seen it enforced without any
> necessity and with almost dogmatic fervor far too many times. The main
> reason I found it useful was because it let me separate complex
> stateful logic from other aspects of the component. Hooks let me do
> the same thing without an arbitrary division. This text is left intact
> for historical reasons but don’t take it too seriously.

With the advent of React hooks the distinction between "smart" and "dumb" components, and "container" and "presentational" components, was all but eliminated.

The common pattern and "best practice" now is to write React Function components and just use the React hooks. In the case of using Redux and React-Redux, the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks instead of the `connect` Higher Order Component. I've not gone out of my way to write a React Class component or split my code between "presentation" and "container" since the advent of React hooks.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is to do it all in one component. Then as you create more and more components you'll see patterns start to emerge. So instead of copying and pasting code from component to component you can make a presentational component that takes in props for what to render. Some of those props can even be what to do when a button is clicked or a box is checked.

Overall your presentational components will end up resembling something like one of the various react js ui frameworks out there such as https://mui.com/